# Why is flex-basis not used for width calculation of enclosing box?

Tags: html, css

In the example below, the combination of `flex-basis` and `flex-shrink` adds a width to the `.space` `div`. But the width isn't used to calculate the width of the outer box (`.parent`). Instead the content is truncated when used in combination with `overflow: hidden`. Why is the width of the `.space` tag discarded?

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent > div {
  display: flex;
}

.space {
  flex-basis: 20px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use width instead of flex-basis (check the "Browser Bugs" section of the duplicate)

Comment: For reference: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=464210